# Incorrect encoding when converting CSV to json

Tags: node.js, json, csv, character-encoding, iconv

I am trying to turn a CSV into a JSON file.
The conversion works correctly, but there seems to be an encoding issue with some of the Spanish characters.
The string appears like this in the CSV: SÁEZ MARÍA
When I import it to node js, it is encoded as utf-8, but the encoding is incorrect, and looks like this: S�EZ MAR�A
I tried converting the encoding to ISO-8859-1, but the result is still encoded incorrectly: Sï¿½EZ MARï¿½A

I am using iconv-lite to make the encoding:

```
let test = axios.get(url, options);
        test.then(response => {
          csv({ //Defying the CSV delimiter
            delimiter: ',',
            trim:true
          })
          .fromString(response.data) //Processing CSV from response
          .then(function(jsonArrayObj){
                var test = iconv.decode(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(user)), "ISO-8859-1");
                console.log(test);
});
```

I also tried just using Buffer.from().toString() with all supported encodings, but none of them solved the issue.
The JSON file comes out in the correct structure, it's just the encoding that's the problem.

Comment: It looks to me like your csv file itself is encoded in iso-8859-1 but your code assumes it is unicode.

Comment: @O.Jones but is there a way to import it as ison-8859-1 to begin with?

Comment: I cannot guess from your example which csv-parsing module you use. But it seems likely that either the `csv()` function or the `fromString` method has an option to specify the character encoding of the input file.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks! I found how to do it. I needed to add responseEncoding:"latin1" to the axios call

Comment: @NimrodYanai you can answer your own question and mark it as solution, it might be interesting for others later ? In this case, provide factual information about `responseEncoding` : what it does, the options available etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment of @O.Jones and the solution:
The issue is that the file was already encoded in latin, but the axios expected utf-8 and encoded accordingly.
The solution was to add

```
responseEncoding:"latin1"
```

to the options I send via the axios call.
This basically tells axios to expect an answer in a different encoding than the default utf-8.

Since the data was read in the correct encoding now, there was no need for further encoding after this.